# Not able to get the active condition from Li in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have the below code to load the controls when I click on different tabs that I have made using `li` and `runat=server`.

But my problem is I need to load the controls based on which `li` tab is active. How can I differentiate which tab (`li`) is clicked from code behind?

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="tabcontrols l_tinynav1">   
    <li class="current" id="li_ActivationBySOID" runat="server">
         <a id="a1" onserverclick="lnk_ActSOID_Click" runat="server" title="Capacity and Flex :Order Number based">Order Number</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="li_Activation" runat="server"><a id="AnchorButton" onserverclick="lnk_Act_Click" runat="server" title="Capacity and Flex:Certificated Id based">Full Redemption</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="li_BActivation" runat="server">
         <a id="a_BACt" onserverclick="lnk_BA_Click" runat="server" title="Flex: Certificate Id based">Partial Redemption</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
loadcontrols(ddlPType.SelectedIndex); // I need to load if li_Activation is active

if (Request.QueryString["PType"] != null)
{
    int ptype = -1;

    if (Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["PType"].ToString(), out ptype))
    {
        loadcontrols(ptype);
        ddlPType.SelectedIndex = ptype;
    }
}

loadOrderNumberControls(ddlPType.SelectedIndex); // I need to load if li_ActivationBySOID is active

if (Request.QueryString["PType"] != null)
{
    int ptype = -1;

    if (Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["PType"].ToString(), out ptype))
    {
        loadOrderNumberControls(ptype);
        ddlPType.SelectedIndex = ptype;
    }
}
```

Could any one please suggest any ideas on this?

**Update:**
I tried with `HiddenField` like this but I am getting empty `string` in code behind:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myList li").click(function () {
        $("#hdnTabField").val($(this).attr('id'));
    });
 })
</script>


<ul class="tabcontrols l_tinynav1" id="myList">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTabField" runat="server" />
    <li class="current" id="li_ActivationBySOID" runat="server">
        <a id="a1"
           onserverclick="lnk_ActSOID_Click"
           runat="server"
           title="Capacity and Flex :Order Number based">Order Number
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="li_Activation" runat="server">
        <a id="AnchorButton"
           onserverclick="lnk_Act_Click"
           runat="server"
           title="Capacity and Flex:Certificated Id based">Full Redemption
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="li_BActivation" runat="server">
        <a id="a_BACt"
           onserverclick="lnk_BA_Click"
           runat="server"
           title="Flex: Certificate Id based">Partial Redemption
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And in code behind:

```
var selectedTab = hdnTabField.Value;
```

Selected tab is getting null value.

Comment: I tried your code and I got the correct value in the hidden field in code-behind.

Comment: i am having aspx page inherited by master page .. i put script inside  <asp:content> tag and i am accessing hidden field value inside page load method.. i am getting null value .. is this is correct way

Comment: @krlzlx where did u put this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `name` property instead of the `id` property for your `li` elements. Using the `id` property, your controls will have an `id` like:

> ContentPlaceHolderName_liNameId

Using the `name` property

```
<li class="" name="li_Activation" runat="server">[...]</li>
```

Then change your JavaScript like this:

```
$("#myList li").click(function () {
    $('input[id$=hdnTabField]').val($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

You should then get the correct value for your hidden field.